# Select and Blank

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I try to filter sublists of a list which match a pattern.

```
test = {{"String1", "a"}, {"String2", "b"}, {"String3", 
"a"}, {"String4", "a"}};
```

The result should be:

```
result = {{"String1", "a"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}}
```

That means the first entry should be any String and the second should be "a".

I tried:

```
Select[test, (# == {_, "a"}) &]
```

Which evaluates to {}.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use `Cases`, then you can give the pattern directly

```
Cases[test, {_String, "a"}]
```

If you want to stick with `Select` you can do this as well but you have to transform your pattern match into a *test function*

```
Select[test, MatchQ[#, {_String, "a"}] &]
```

Comment: ah get it. Select needs an explicit test function. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility:

```
Pick[#, (Thread@#)[[2]], "a"] &@test
```

> ```
> {{"String1", "a"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}}
> ```

Comment: being curious: why do you use `Thread`, instead of e.g. `Pick[#, #[[All, 2]], "a"] &@test`?

Comment: Please notice that OP has said: "first entry should be any String"

Comment: But the OP did NOT say 'any _string_' (note the capital).

Comment: What do you mean? I understand this as first element's head must be string, your code will accept any.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the first value could be any one of "String1", "String2", "String3", "String4" (any first value).  For example, what the OP tried was `Select[test, (# == {_, "a"}) &]`.  No mention of _string_ (lower-case) there.  I know what my code does,  btw.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
Select[test, Function[{x}, StringQ[x[[1]]] && x[[2]] == "a"]]
```

> ```
> {{"String1","a"},{"String3","a"},{"String4","a"}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{"String1", "a"}, {"String2", "b"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}};

Pick[list, SameAs["a"] /@ Last /@ list]
```

{{"String1", "a"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}}

`SameAs` came with V 13.1

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{"String1", "a"}, {"String2", "b"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}};
```

---

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {_String, "a"}, ___} :> s]

(*{{"String1", "a"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {s : {_String, "a"}} :> s]

(*{{"String1", "a"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceSplit`:

```
(# /. Flatten@SequenceSplit[#, {{Except["a"], "a"}}] -> Nothing) &@list

(*{{"String1", "a"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"String1", "a"}, {"String2", "b"}, {"String3", 
    "a"}, {"String4", "a"}};
```

---

```
Select[list, Last@# == "a" &]
Select[EqualTo["a"]@*Last][list]
Select[IntersectingQ[{_, "a"}, #] &][list]
Pick[list, list[[All, 2]], "a"] (*taken*)
Pick[list, SameQ[Last@#, "a"] & /@ list] 
GroupBy[Last][list]["a"]
Cases[list, {s_String, "a"}]  (*taken*)
DeleteCases[list, {_String, Except["a"]}]
Extract[list, Position[list[[All, 2]], "a"]]
Replace[list, {_, Except["a"]} :> Nothing, 1]
```

---

> {{"String1", "a"}, {"String3", "a"}, {"String4", "a"}}